# OpenGL Redbook, OpenGL Programming Guide - Version 2 or Version 2.1 - Looking for advice on which to purchace

Tags: opengl

## Borrowed a book from the Uni Library. It wasn't what I was hoping for...

Hi, I am a student and over the summer I borrowed the OpenGL Programming Guide, for version 4.3, which was the only version my University seemed to have in the main library.

I already know a little bit about using OpenGL with SFML, SDL and glut. I borrowed the book to help me extend my knowledge.

Unfortunately I have found the 4.3 book very heavy going and difficult to follow. I was sure I had read a similar book (an older version, when it used to be called "redbook") and found it much easier to follow.

I was able to borrow the Version 2.1 book, and I am fairly sure this was the one I had read parts of. So far I have found it *much* easier to follow. It is certainly much better suited to non-experts and people with less experience.

## Please don't close this question...

This might be the sort of question which gets poor reception, and gets voted to close, but please don't do that - I would like an answer to my question. I think this is a programming question, and would be helpful to others like myself. As I explain later, I am looking to buy the book for Version 2 or Version 2.1, and would like some advice.

## TLDR? Question starts here:

Basically I would like to know what the main differences are between OpenGL Version 2 and Version 2.1. As far as I can tell, there is a book for Version 1.0 or something like that, then 2.0, 2.1, and then 3 or 3.5 or something. Why is there a *whole new book* for a version increment of 0.1: As in from Version 2.0 to 2.1. I am assuming some major changes were made or extensions and functionality added in the 2.1 release?

Reason for asking is I liked the book (Version 2.1) so much, I thought I should buy it! (Madness, no?) Anyway, I want to know what extra stuff is in Version 2.1, or what has changed, so I can made a decision about if spending extra is worth it.

Comment: OpenGL has sort of a classic version, and a modern version, with non fixed render pipelines, which would you like to learn... desktop or embedded could make a difference as GL !=GL ES

Comment: Probably the classic version? I want to be able to do thinks like render particles and such for physics experiments on desktop (linux - ubuntu, debian, fedora) computers.

Comment: 2.0 or 2.1? Neither obviously. OpenGL 4.3 has a lot of improvements, and you can just skip harder parts

Answer (score 8):

This is probably not the answer you were hoping for, but: don't bother learning OGL < 3.0. All of OpenGL is well documented and everything you need to know can be found on the internet. Also note the redbook is entirely free on the internet, at least the relevant parts (as far as I'm aware). Anyway, it heavily focuses on the older, deprecated functionality, I wouldn't consider it worth reading anymore.

OpenGL 3.0 introduced the deprecation mechanism, thus most of OpenGL 2.x features were deprecated. This includes client side memory, fixed pipeline, built in lighting calculation etc. OpenGL 2.x does include programmable pipeline features and server side buffers, but I would still strongly recommend using modern OGL. Simply because you can't be cautious enough. OpenGL 2.x invites you to use older functionality, as it is terribly easy to use, but possibly a felony.

The programmable pipeline, server side buffers and all the goods from OpenGL 3.x and up are perhaps hard to learn about. But once you're able to proficiently use these features, you will be blown away by its power. In your comment you mentioned particles, it is so much more fun to experiment with particles if you have the ability to use transform feedbacks, compute shaders, geometry shaders, instanced rendering and so on. The truth is that modern OpenGL is hugely supperior to older OpenGL, it is much, much faster and designed for modern hardware.

I don't know why each minor version has a new book, people have an addiction to books I suppose. But OpenGL 3.x and up really deserves a new book. It is entirely different from previous APIs - at least its usage is. Now I personally dislike books, but that's just me. A great starting point to learn about OpenGL 3.x and up on the internet would be:

http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/index.html

http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/

http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/

The first link is a great source for getting to know the pipeline, I strongly recommend reading it all. I really like the second link, it has a bunch of small tutorials on a range of subjects, it is also a great source to get to know more complex algorithms. The third link is a more beginner style tutorial in case you get stuck.

Also this one has all the information and detailed documentation you could ever wish for, keep track of it regardless of what source you're going to use:

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Main_Page

You also mentioned you want to experiment on a linux environment. Make sure to update your OpenGL drivers (do this on any OS actually). Now according to the website Mesa only supports up to OpenGL 3.1. I would recommend using proprietary drivers just so you can use all of what your GPU has to offer (personally, I'm running OpenGL 4.2 on linux mint using AMD drivers), this includes things like geometry shaders, tesselation and similar.

One last note, OpenGL ES 2.0+ is easier to convert to/from newer OpenGL versions. OpenGL ES 2.0+ does not use fixed pipeline, nor client side memory and alike. And a similar API runs on the web, even the web has moved on, so should you :P

Now get out there and start OGL'in!

Comment: Okay that sounds like sound advice. Thank you for your detailed answer. I will try to get to grips with version 3.x / 4.x

Comment: Agreed. Situation with books about OpenGL makes me sad.

Comment: GL 3.2/3 is a good start. It has good support across different platform.

Comment: Might I add, OS X 10.7 and up seem to have support up to GL 3.2. On windows and linux most will be able to get the newest GL version supported by their hardware. So if I were you I'd support at least 3.2 for most desktop environments.